# tsql user-defined functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

Is it possible to call a user-defined function in TSQL without the scoping qualifier. I want to call

```
select myfunc(var)
```

and not

```
select dbo.myfunc(var)
select myschema.myfunc(var)
```

It's possible in every other DB that I've ever worked with (7 others) it has to be possible in tsql too.

If I'm signed into my DB/schema I don't have to qualify a table reference... i can do

```
select * from mytable
```

without the qualifier... why aren't function calls orthogonal to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Executing User-Defined Functions (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175562.aspx) on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/):

> ...Scalar-valued functions must be
>   invoked by using at least the two-part
>   name of the function...

The writing between the lines here is that the schema name is not required for table-valued [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189593.aspx)s, but I have not personally tested this.

Comment: Good RTFM thanks. Altho this answer will cause massive problems for porting legacy software to MSSQL 2008... I am not impressed

Comment: There is not a lot of documentation out there on the "why" part.  Sorry this wasn't a satisfactory response.